# Converting lap times from weird format to seconds only

Tags: r, time

In the [dataset](https://www.sportsvizsunday.com/formula-1) "Australian Grand Prix" I can't figure out how to turn the "time" variable column from the (character) format "1M 43.702S" to just seconds in the format "103.702" as a numeric.

edit: The "1M 43.702s" is just the first time in the column, what is the best way for converting the whole column?

Does anyone know a nice way of doing this?

Comment: Could you show what has failed or provide a `dput` of the data?

Answer (score 1):

For a base R option, we can use `sub` to extract the minute and second components as strings, cast them to numeric, and take the sum:

```r
x <- "1M 43.702S"
m <- 60*as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)M.*$", "\\1", x))
s <- as.numeric(sub("^.*(?<!\\S)(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)S$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE))
output <- m + s
output

[1] 103.702
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't know if you've looked at the dataset, but I need to change the entire column in the dataset like this. Is there a nice way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate`

```
time_str = "1M 43.702S"     
lubridate::seconds(lubridate::ms(time_str))
    [1] "103.702S"
```

If you need it as a numeric (suggestion by @Allan Cameron):

```
 as.numeric(lubridate::seconds(lubridate::ms(time_str)))
[1] 103.702
```